# If a DAC does USB in and S/PDIF out, what does it do?

Tags: driver, dac, music

I have a USB DAC (Creative SB1240) and their recommended connection is to take an S/PDIF or USB in (to the DAC) and an S/PDIF out (to a receiver). This is how I have connected it and it does sound better than my laptop directly going to the receiver.

The question is:
The DAC is taking digital in and giving a digital out. Where is its conversion capability being used here? If it is not the conversion capability, then what magic is it doing here?

Software Used:
FooBar player & WASAPI.

Comment: People may refer to it offhand as a "DAC" and that is likely one of its capabilities, but it is advertised as a "USB Audio System" which would be a more appropriate description for how you are using it.

Comment: I think you should explain in further detail how things are connected. How do you precisely connect your laptop to your receiver? Maybe two drawings of your two setups? Do you use S/PDIF in all cases for all cables? Please add a link to a product page of the SB1204

Comment: @jippie I've explained this. It's connected to the laptop via USB and to the receiver via S/PDIF. The receiver is in turn connected to the speakers. I think the answer below confirms my thought - that it is acting as a pass-thru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just relaying digital audio through, assuming there is no corruption (possible with S/PDIF if there is jitter/wander on the clock) then there is no magic, the information is exactly the same as connecting directly. If it sounds different, then it's doing some DSP (Digital Signal Processing) though I'd assume you should have some control over this.

The actual DAC (Digital to Analogue Converter) is a chip inside your box and is only used for part of the whole function - the product itself is not a "DAC", it's a USB audio system as Chris says in the comments. The DAC is used for converting the digital audio on your PC back into analogue signals.
It will also have an ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter) to perform the reverse for the inputs (mic/line in) and a DSP capable microcontroller to apply any filtering, effects and suchlike.

For reading of digital information, it either works perfectly or it doesn't, there is no in between. For example, a cheap CD drive will read a CD just as well as an expensive one, it's up to the DAC and output amplifier to recreate the signal correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As you say, it might just be a pass-thru here because DSP doesn't work on this device when I use digital out. It works only when I use the analog out. The better quality is possibly because the analog conversion now takes place in the receiver instead of the laptop. Earlier I used to connect the audio out (i.e. already converted) to the receiver, as my laptop doesn't have a digital out.